# 301 Redirect server IP to domain while keeping query string

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I've searched around but no one has the exact issue as me, I can't figure out how to do this without messing up the site.

-My website is WordPress.
-Vultr VPS with Server Pilot 
-Currently the site is behind cloudflare and this all works.

Issue: I have an entire version of the website still browsable using the server IP and I can't figure out how to 301 redirect it.

Example if you happen to go to my website xxx.x.xx.xx then you can browse the entire website without ever being redirected, the query strings and everything shows in the address bar example:

http://xxx.x.xx.xx/category/page/?utm_source=aa&utm_medium=bb&utm_campaign=cc

Someone could browse the entire site like this, I do not want this I want to redirect it to my domain. In WordPress general settings I do have the Site URL and WordPress URL set to my domain name but I don't know why this is happening.

I can't give examples of what I've tried because they all failed and I had to delete them from my .htaccess file, basically, *I want to 301 redirect any request coming to the IP and send them to the domain of the site carrying over their query string and everything*, help is really appreciated.

Comment: Do you have access to the server with an FTP client?

Comment: @Kobbe yes I do, I have been trying some snippets but they all mess up the site one way or another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by using the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xx\.xx\.xxx\.xxx
RewriteRule (.*)  https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Dot's must be escaped and the query strings get carried along just fine, be sure to leave the trailing slash as it's displayed above or else your page might appear like this: https://example.compage/subpage

Leaving the trailing slash in the rewrite rule will prevent that so it would be: https://example.com/page/subpage

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this in your .htaccess file?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Redirect 301 /old_page1/ http://example.com/new_page1
Redirect 301 /old_page2/ http://example.com/new_page2
```

Comment: I saw similar solutions but this doesnt seem like it would work, I am trying to redirect requests coming to the server IP example:

http://123.123.123.123/mypage/mysubpage?a_query_string=string

to the actual domain while keeping query strings (if present):

https://example.com/mypage/mysubpage?a_query_string=string

Additionally all requests trying to be made to the server IP should just go to the domain...right now someone can browse the entire site via It's IP which is not good, I'm using WordPress by the way.